# regular Cauchy data for wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

From Salsa, [PDEs in Action](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-15093-2), chapter 5.

> Let $w_\phi$ be the solution of the Cauchy problem
>   \begin{array}{l}
> w_{tt}-c^2 \Delta w=0 \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3,\; t>0 \\ 
> w(x,0) = 0 \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3 \\ 
> w_t(x,0)=\phi(x) \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3
> \end{array}
>   such that $w\in C^3(\mathbb{R}^3\times[0,+\infty))$.
>
> Then $v\equiv \partial_t w_\phi$ is the solution of the Cauchy problem 
>   \begin{array}{l}
> v_{tt}-c^2 \Delta v=0 \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3,\; t>0 \\
> v(x,0) = \phi(x) \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3 \\
> v_t(x,0)=0 \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3
> \end{array}

This lemma, combined with the superposition principle, simplifies the solution of the Cauchy problem with both Cauchy data.

I cannot figure out how to verify that $ v_t(x,0) = 0$.
Here are the steps I have made:
\begin{equation*}
v_t(x,0) = \partial_{tt} w_\phi(x,0)
= \lim_{t\to 0^+} \partial_{tt} w_\phi(x,t)
= \lim_{t\to 0^+} c^2\Delta w_\phi(x,t)
= c^2\Delta w_\phi(x,0)
\end{equation*}
where the limits hold due to the regularity of $w_\phi$.

Why is the last term equal to zero? 
In other words, why is $w_\phi(\cdot,0)$ harmonic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have specified that $w(x, 0) = 0$.  Doesn't this imply $\Delta w_\phi(x, 0) = 0$, since $w_\phi = w$ when $t = 0$?

Comment: Then why bother using the wave equation in the first place? Since $v(x,0)=\phi(x)$, then $v_t(x,0)=0$ because $\phi$ does not depend on $t$. I have always thought that you should apply the operator first and then calculate the value of the function on the specified point.

Comment: Those are two different concepts: the difference between $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dx}(w(x))$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} w(x))$

Comment: @DaveNine and that's exactly my point--and my issue: $\Delta w_\phi (x,0) =\lim_{t\to 0^+} \Delta w_\phi (x,t) \neq \Delta \lim_{t\to 0^+} w_\phi (x,t) =\Delta w_\phi (x,0) =\Delta 0 = 0$

Comment: @GiovanniMariani First of all I apologize for searching for you here in a place where it is not supposed for me to comment here. But, please, help me with this? I only would like at least a hint, a small tip. Please, help me, I know from your profile that you are good at pde classic theory. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797950/what-hypothesis-can-i-assum-in-order-to-obtain-infinity-solutions-for-this-probl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a reason why $c^2 \Delta w_\phi(x,0)=0$.
Since the Laplacian acts only on the space variables $x$ and leaves the time variable $t$ unchanged, we have
$$ (\Delta w_\phi)(x,0) = \Delta (w_\phi(x,0)) = 0 \quad\text{since}\quad w_\phi(x,0)=0 $$
In other words, taking the Laplacian and then letting $t=0$ or vice-versa yield the same result.

Incidentally, this is why one must use the wave equation via the limits and cannot simply stop at $\partial_{tt} w_\phi$: actually
$$ (\partial_{tt} w_\phi)(x,0) \neq \partial_{tt} (w_\phi(x,0))$$
My comment above on this point was misleading.